# With Eclipse Che v6.0.0 + OCP v3.6, bootstrapper is corrupted when creating workspace

Tags: openshift, eclipse-che

I constructed the environment of Eclipse Che v6.0.0 + OCP v3.6(v3.6.173.0.96) by the same procedure as the following issue.
[Workspace of MultiUser Eclipse-che can not be started on OCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898193/workspace-of-multiuser-eclipse-che-can-not-be-started-on-ocp)

I confirmed that Workspace pod can be started with OCP 3.6.
However, the Workspace screen can not be displayed in the browser.
The following message is displayed in the browser.

```
Could not start workspace wksp-vryu. Reason: Bootstrapping of machine dev-machine reached timeout
```

From the browser console of OpenShift, when I executed the following command with Workspace pod, I noticed that bootstrapper size was wrong.
The result of executing the command is as follows.

```
$ cd /tmp/bootstrapper
$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user root    69 Feb 26 05:32 .
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root    49 Feb 26 05:32 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 user root   250 Feb 26 05:32 bootstrapper
-rw-r--r--. 1 user root   100 Feb 26 05:32 bootstrapper.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 user root 23906 Feb 26 05:32 config.json
```

The content of the bootstrapper was as follows.

```
$ cat bootstrapper                                                                                                                                                     
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">                                                                                                                     
<html><head>                                                                                                                                                           
<title>404 Not Found</title>                                                                                                                                           
</head><body>                                                                                                                                                          
<h1>Not Found</h1>                                                                                                                                                     
<p>The requested URL /agent-binaries/linux_amd64/bootstrapper/bootstrapper was not found on this server.</p>                                                           
</body></html>
```

In the workspace pod, we manually executed the wget command using CHE_INFRA_KUBERNETES_BOOTSTRAPPER_BINARY__URL in environment variable of Che Server's pod. I can successfully download boostrapper.

```
$ wget http://<My Route name>-<My Project Name>.<My Prefix>/agent-binaries/linux_amd64/bootstrapper/bootstrapper
--2018-02-26 06:19:25--  http://<My Route name>-<My Project Name>.<My Prefix>/agent-binaries/linux_amd64/bootstrapper/bootstrapper
Resolving <My Route name>-<My Project Name>.<My Prefix> (<My Route name>-<My Project Name>.<My Prefix>)... <Che Server's Node IP>
Connecting to <My Route name>-<My Project Name>.<My Prefix> (<My Route name>-<My Project Name>.<My Prefix>)|<Che Server's Node IP>|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200
Length: 6146825 (5.9M)
Saving to: ‘bootstrapper’

bootstrapper        100%[===================>]   5.86M  --.-KB/s    in 0.08s

2018-02-26 06:19:26 (73.1 MB/s) - ‘bootstrapper’ saved [6146825/6146825]

$ ls -l
total 6032
-rw-r--r--. 1 user root 6146825 Jan 31 15:07 bootstrapper
-rw-r--r--. 1 user root      49 Feb 26 06:15 bootstrapper.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 user root   23906 Feb 26 06:15 config.json
```

How can I solve this problem?
Please let me know if there is information to help.

Comment: Can be related to https://github.com/eclipse/che/pull/8805 and fixed in latest Che 6

Answer (score 0):

`CHE_INFRA_KUBERNETES_BOOTSTRAPPER_BINARY__URL` was introduced only in Eclipse Che 6.1.0. Related PR https://github.com/eclipse/che/pull/8559.
So, Che Server code expects `CHE_INFRA_OPENSHIFT_BOOTSTRAPPER_BINARY__URL` and it has wrong value.

I suppose the scripts that you used is not compatible with 6.0.0 Che. Please try to deploy Che 6.1.0. It is recommended to use the deploy script with the same version as Che has. So, try to use checkout to tag.